# Is it possible to load a usercontrol via a Uri in Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, windows-phone-7.1

In WP7 you can easily navigate to a new page via NavigationService.

Eg. _navigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/SamplePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Is it possible to load a user control via a Uri.

eg. UserControl sampleControl = MagicLoadFunction(new Uri("/Controls/SampleControl.xaml", UriKind.Relative))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the control/ xaml file only contained xaml and no code behind you could load the file as text and then call [`XamlReader.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190359%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on it.

Alternatively, if you knew the type the control you coudl just new up an instance and there woudl be no need to load it via a Uri. The type would already be compiled.

Or if you're trying to have some way of making a countrol where you can change the XAML it shows, then just use templating or make it a ContentPresenter and dynamically set the content.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot - the framework only allows you to navigate to pages. I am not sure why you would want to navigate to a user control? You can simply host this control within a page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    ...
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpaceHere">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <local:SampleControl/>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Then navigate to the page rather than your user control directly.

Comment: I think you can actually navigate to UserControl (found that by accident) but that is not what I want to do. I want to new up an instance of a view using URI.